# SQL Server : calculating days elapsed

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the number of elapsed days between any two dates with respect to the current date.  IE:

```
mm/dd/yyyy

Current day = 07/10/2015  
07/08/2013 ...  07/11/2013 - 4 days elapsed

Current day = 07/10/2015  
07/08/2015 ... 07/11/2015 - 2 days have elapsed
```

I've tried several combinations using `DATEDIFF` with `day` as the date part, however, I can't seem to get a clean way to get the days elapsed when the date could be past or present.

**EDIT**

I know the start date and the end date of a certain business process. They could be this year, last year, two years ago and so on. I need a way via SQL Server functions to figure out the days total elapsed. If it's not the current year, obviously the entire span/range would have elapsed.  If it's the current year, perhaps the entire span/range hasn't elapsed and it needs to say how many days are "into the process" based on the respected start time, end time and current time.

Hopefully this makes more sense?

Please help.

**I used @Sean Lange, with a small tweak:
DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, case when @EndDate < GETDATE() then @EndDate + 1 else GETDATE() end)

Thanks all.**

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the issue is here. Can you please try to explain your issue more clearly?

Comment: I know it needs to be sql. What I don't understand is the issue. The sample data you posted doesn't seem to match up with the sample output. There just isn't enough information posted here to allow us to help much.

Comment: @dnapierata I personally dislike using the datetpart shortcuts and prefer to use the full name. DATEADD(DAY is immediately clear where DATEADD(d is not really so obvious. It gets more confusing for things like month and minute. That of course is just my opinion and either of them will work.

Comment: Sean please forgive, i'm a .net DEV who doesn't tamper with SQL often, but this task requires it to be done in SQL.  I've updated my question to just explain what I need to happen.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would help more than a text based explanation is some actual sample data and desired output. Throw up a quick temp table or cte with your sample data.

Comment: I am totally confused how the same dates can have a different number of days elapsed in the different years. And why would it be either 2 or 4? It sure seems to be 3 days between the start and end dates. But it is not at all clear what the current date has to do with this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the CASE statement?   Your solution needs to include a "CASE EndDate>GETDATE()" statement.

Comment: @SeanLange he wants the number of elapsed days from either the startdate to the enddate if the enddate is in the past, or from the startdate to the currentdate if the enddate is in the future.

Comment: Wow @TabAlleman that is impressive you figured that out but I think you are spot on. I just simply wasn't getting that at all.

Comment: @Tab Alleman, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve.  I figured there would be a cleaner way than to use a CASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty similar to the answer provided by Stan but here is my take on this.

```
with Something as
(
    select CAST('2013-07-08' as datetime) as StartDate
        , CAST('2013-07-11' as datetime) as EndDate
    union all
    select '2015-07-08', '2015-07-11'
)

select *
    , DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, case when EndDate < GETDATE() then EndDate else GETDATE() end)
from Something
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test ( ChildID INT Identity,
                            Start   DateTime
                    ,       Finish  DateTime
                    )
```

and your test data:

```
insert into dbo.test (start,finish) values('07/08/2013','07/11/2013')
insert into dbo.test (start,finish) values('07/08/2015','07/11/2015')
```

then

```
select start,finish
 , DATEDIFF(DAY, start, CASE WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN start and finish 
             THEN GETDATE() - 1  ELSE finish END) + 1 as elapsed
 from dbo.test
```

gives the result from your example.

You might have to tweak if there are other adjustments for how the current date fits `between` the range.

Comment: insert into dbo.test (start,finish) values('07/07/2015','07/11/2015') still produces 2 (should be 3) - I will need to look into this more as now I least know the CASE statement (CTE stuff confuses me more) is what I'll need to apply.  I appreciate it Stan, and everyone else.